# Why Hanson's logarithmic scoring rule define an Automated Market Maker?

Tags: markets, financial-markets

Why Hanson's logarithmic scoring rule define an Automated Market Maker?
We have in [this paper](http://users.wfu.edu/strumpks/papers/JPMFinalVersion(JPM%203-1%20complete%20text%20310309).pdf)
in page 47, section automated market maker, that this scoring rule can "easily" be turned into an AMM. But it seems to be so easy that no one can explain that clearly. Sometimes, LMSR is directly defined as an AMM like [here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7E./sandholm/liquidity-sensitive%20automated%20market%20maker.teac.pdf)
middle of page 2.
Well, in all research I did, everyone consider that it's an AMM, but Hanson do not really explain why...

Comment: please use the hyperlink function (shortcut: CTRL+L) when inserting links otherwise the text easily becomes unintelligible.

Comment: I was wondering about the same and found the answer in Section 5 of this paper: https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1206/1206.5252.pdf